# How to see the all files that are in workspace tree and not in depot ?

Tags: perforce

How can I see list of files that exist in the workspace but **don't exist in depot** ? 
I want to "mark for add" those files.

Comment: `p4 status` should show you that list. If you instead run `p4 reconcile -a` it will even do the "mark for add" for you.

Answer (score 0):

From P4V, choose "Reconcile Offline Work" from the top level of files you wish to, uh, reconcile. It will nicely let you add files that are not in the depot.

From the command line "p4 reconcile -a" will open-for-add any files that are not in the depot.